# htaccess Rewrite rules with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following files on my server root:

```
/index.php
/css/file.css
/js/file.js
```

I would like to redirect :

- `http://host/entry/1` to `http://host/index.php?entry=1`

I have the following `.htaccess` so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /entry/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^entry/(.*)$ index.php?entry=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem is that the `css` and `js` files are not served correctly.

And that is because the browser asks for the files:

- `http://host/entry/css/file.css` instead of `http://host/css/file.css`
- `http://host/entry/js/file.js` instead of `http://host/js/file.js`

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're missing a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: it doesn't help much :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^entry/(.+\.(?:js|css))$ $1 [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^/content/ag(.*)$ index.php?entry=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^entry/(.*)$ index.php?entry=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

And add in your html header:

```
<base href="/">
```

I add rewrite for .js and .css
But you can add others, like .gif or .png...

Comment: is there any other solution instead of the `<base href='/'>` which might be a problem for my `js` code ?